# undefined behaviour in cpp program

Tags: c++

I am new to cpp I know my question is very silly but i have no help other than here,whats wrong with if block and i am very correct with my logic but i don't why my program is giving TLE because of if block

Online judge link [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-postorder-traversal/submissions/)

when i am changing the if loop

```
if((st.empty()==false)&&(st.top()==root)){
        root=root->right;
         }else{
         ans.push_back(root->val);
         root=NULL;
  }
```

picked from below program then it is running fine ,Please help me 
I am new to cpp,I was earlier programming in python Please help.
whats wrong with my if block

This is my solution is getting TLE

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> postorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
        stack<TreeNode*>st;
        vector<int>ans;
        while(root||!st.empty()){
            while(root){
                st.push(root);
                st.push(root);
                root=root->left;
            }

            if(st.empty())return ans;
            root = st.top();
            st.pop();

            if((st.empty()==false)&&(st.top()==root)){  //if((st.empty()==false)&&(st.top()==root))
                root==root->right;
            }else{
                ans.push_back(root->val);
                root=NULL;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Below solution is accepted

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> postorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
        stack<TreeNode*>st;
        vector<int>ans;
        while(root||!st.empty()){
            while(root){
                st.push(root);
                st.push(root);
                root=root->left;
            }

            if(st.empty())return ans;
            root = st.top();
            st.pop();
            if((st.empty()==false)&&(st.top()==root)){
                root=root->right;
            }else{
                ans.push_back(root->val);
                root=NULL;
            }


        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: "*i have no help other than here*" - that's not true. You can help yourself by using a *debugger*.

Comment: So the question is a game of spot the difference between the 2 solutions? I am confused, maybe my coffee hasn't activated yet but both codes look the same.

Comment: please help @drescherjm both program are same but control is not going in if loop

Comment: There's a cool tool called `diff`, which can help you spot the difference (and it comes with multiple online versions too): https://www.diffchecker.com/WLFPG6Ej But learning [how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is going to serve you much better in the future, when there is no ready solution to compare to.

Comment: @drescherjm "_but both codes look the same._" The only difference between those 2 solutions (despite the comment) is: `root==root->right;` in first, became `root=root->right;` in second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
if((st.empty()==false)&&(st.top()==root)){  //if((st.empty()==false)&&(st.top()==root))
    root==root->right;
```

You are not assigning into `root`, you're comparing it.

Fix:

```
    root=root->right;
```